# Incorporating GZIP into Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, compression, gzip, asp.net-web-api2

I have a C# application that communicates to my Web API service fine when there is no GZIP being used.  When I apply GZIP, my [FromBody] variable is null and I can't seem to pinpoint why this is happening.

If I put a breakpoint in the web api, I can see that data is null when GZIP is applied.  When it's not, it is populated.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.  If you need any other code examples please let me know

Update Routing Class

```
public class UpdateRouting
{
    public UpdateRouting()
    {
        Routes = new List<Routing>();
    }
    public List<Routing> Routes { get; set; }
}
```

Collect data

```
private void btnTestRoutingSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = new ResponseObj();
            using (var mainContext = new EntityModel())
            {
                var nodes = mainContext.Nodes.Where(x => x.SystemType == "Dev").ToList();
                var updRouting = new UpdateRouting();
                foreach (var n in nodes)
                {
                    using (var nodeContext = new EntityModel(connString))
                    {
                        var accounts = nodeContext.Accounts;
                        foreach (var acct in accounts)
                        {
                            //code to map accounts to route
                        }

                        var customers = nodeContext.Customers;
                        foreach (var cust in customers)
                        {
                            //code to map customer to route
                        }
                    }
                }
                response = webcontext.SendPost<ResponseObj>(updRouting, "Routing", "SyncRouting");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

SendPost Method

```
public T SendPost<T>(object update, string controller, string action)
    {
        var url = _baseURL + String.Format("api/{0}/{1}", controller, action), update);

        T retval = default(T);
        var uri = new Uri(_baseUri, url);
        try
        {
            var request = GetRequest(uri, method);

            if (content != null)
            {
                var json = GetBodyString(content);
                if (!_useCompression)
                {
                    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                    {
                        var json = GetBodyString(content);
                        streamWriter.Write(json);
                        streamWriter.Flush();
                        streamWriter.Close();
                    }
                } else{    
                    using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(request.GetRequestStream(), CompressionMode.Compress, false))
                    {
                        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(gzipStream))
                        {
                            streamWriter.Write(json);
                            streamWriter.Flush();
                            streamWriter.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
                }
            }

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                retval = GetObject<T>(result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _log.Error(string.Format("Error sending {0} request to {1}", method, uri.ToString()), e);
        }
        return retval;
    }
```

Get Request

```
protected virtual HttpWebRequest GetRequest(Uri uri, string method)
    {
        var retval = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        retval.Timeout = 1000 * 60 * 5;
        retval.Accept = "application/json";
        retval.KeepAlive = true;
        retval.ContentType = "application/json";
        retval.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        retval.Method = method;

        return retval;
    }
```

API Call

```
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        [Route("SyncRouting")]
    public ResponseObj SyncRouting([FromBody] UpdateRouting data)
    {
        var response = new ResponseObj();
        try
        {
            // do stuff
            response.Successful = true;
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            response.Successful = false;
            response.Errors.Add(new ErrorMsg
            {
                Message = "Error - " + e.ToString(),
                ExceptionMessage = e.Message,
                StackTrace = e.StackTrace,
                InnerException = e.InnerException.ToString()
            });

            return response;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should add a delegating handler to decompress incoming request base on headers.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not just enabling gzip compression in IIS or web.confg?

Comment: @dotctor Thanks! That definitely saved me some time.  I can't mark it as an answer though so if you mark post an answer I will mark it as correct.